# Connection pooling in .Net Sql Provider - when connection is closed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, connection-pooling

I just wonder after what duration .Net Sql Provider will close connection which is in pool?

Thanks, Pawel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) does not specify how long connections in the connection pool stay open.  The optimizer decides, and its algorithm might change between versions of ADO.NET (or maybe even Windows Update patches.)

You can control the maximum lifetime through a [connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) setting:

```
Connection Lifetime=0
```

By default, it's 0, which means a connection can live as long as the optimizer thinks it's useful.